# Bitwise GCD Challenge

Tags: code-golf, math, restricted-source

Write the shortest iterative function to find gcd of two numbers (assume 32 bit numbers).

**Rules:**

- Arithmetic, Comparison and Logical Operators are not allowed **(except equality comparison (`a==b`) operator)**.
- Function should work for both positive and negative numbers
- No inbuilt functions allowed.
- All bitwise operators allowed.

Comment: What _is_ allowed in the loop head? Only zero-test?

Comment: @JanDvorak Can be anything, but within the limit of the rules

Comment: ok, does equality test count as comparison, or do we have to do a poor-man's XOR followed by a zero-check?

Comment: @JanDvorak No comparison operator allowed. You can use your second idea.

Comment: @JanDvorak Unfortunately XOR is also not allowed and has to be replaced by `(a|b)&!(a&b)`. Together with no comparisons allowed this seems rather arbitrary to me and disqualifies lots of languages. Not interesting.

Comment: Are we at least allowed to do `== 0` in languages where 0 is truthy?

Comment: there were some unnecessary restrictions, I updated them

Comment: possible duplicate of [math with bitwise operators](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12706/math-with-bitwise-operators)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Python - 196 bytes

```
def A(a,b):
 while b:a,b=a&~b|~a&b,(a&b)<<1
 return a
def G(a,b,i=0):
 if a>>31:a=A(~a,1)
 if b>>31:b=A(~b,1)
 while~a&b|a&~b:c,d=~a&1,~b&1;i=A(i,c&d);a,b=[b,a>>c,A(a,b),b>>d][c|d::2]
 return a<<i
```

Sample usage:

```
from random import randint
for i in range(10):
  a = randint(-2147483647,2147483647)
  b = randint(-2147483647,2147483647)
  print 'gcd(%d, %d) = %d'%(a, b, G(a,b))
```

Sample output:

```
gcd(-36916085, -1872111029) = 1
gcd(1355889652, 1816917540) = 188
gcd(-366482295, 1612196424) = 9
gcd(836632083, -1156302534) = 3
gcd(1223074731, -1299765354) = 123
gcd(-1154829176, 522085100) = 4
gcd(-1673024403, 1589241938) = 1
gcd(-1871498822, -1089342630) = 2
gcd(1653429392, 2095617430) = 2
gcd(1525670601, -1985869899) = 39
```

---

#### Implementation Notes

- `A` -> a function which adds two integers.
- `a&~b|~a&b` -> `a^b`
- `if a>>31` -> `if a<0`
- `a=A(~a,1)` -> `a=-a` (taken together, `if a>>31:a=A(~a,1)` -> `a=abs(a)`)
- `~a&1` -> `a%2==0` a.k.a. `a` is even.

The function `G` begins by removing powers of 2 from both `a` and `b` (and shifting the result if both are even). When both `a` and `b` are odd, it continues on with `a=b, b=(a+b)/2`. This works because `gcd(a, b) = gcd(a, a+b)`, and `a+b` is necessarily even. This would terminate noticeably sooner using a comparison and a subtraction (subtracting the smaller value from the larger), but neither are available.

Comment: great!!, first to answer

Comment: you are using recursion, please do it iteratively..

Comment: please, verify if the description was ambiguous "Write the shortest iterative function to find gcd of two numbers". If ambiguous, recursion will be fine and I will update the question else you have to update the code :P

Comment: I apologize. I must have skipped over the word 'iterative' while reading the description.